# Dbus ipc communication problems

Tags: c, client-server, ipc, dbus

I have a code where the client is a normal C application(non-root) which gets messages from a server which is running with root permissions . For IPC am using D-BUS.
Everything runs fine if both are running as root, but i don't want the client to be root at anypoint.
the DBUS which is been used is DBUS_BUS_SESSION.

Comment: did you check if the policy imposes to be root or not ?

Comment: What are the failure symptoms when you run the client as non-root? Error messages? Messages in the system log? Identifiably incorrect traffic from `dbus-monitor --session`? If the service is running as root, it’s likely registered on the D-Bus system bus, not the session bus.

Comment: Failed to get a session DBus connection: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
: failed dbus communication

Comment: Hi Vishal, How did you run the dbus-daemon --system as root? I am trying to punch holes  to IPC recieve   data from a worker thread running as root. but the msgrcv() is failing running in the bluetooth time plugin is failing since it runs as messageBus user.